# OCaml file reader

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexer

i am defining a language in ocaml with ocamllex and ocamlyacc. The input for this language is a stream of ints from a file, for example:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`open_in` takes a file name and returns a channel for this file. Here you give it `stdin` which is already a channel.

Comment: You should give it the name of your file.